# What is the fastest way to find the point of intersection between a ray and a polygon?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, raytracing

Pretty much as the question asks. Answers preferably in pseudo code and referenced. The correct answer should value speed over simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Intersections of Rays, Segments, Planes and Triangles in 3D](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330124410/http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html). You can find ways to triangulate polygons.

If you really need ray/polygon intersection, it's on 16.9 of [Real-Time Rendering](http://www.realtimerendering.com/) (13.8 for 2nd ed).

> We first compute the intersection
> between the ray and [the plane of the
> ploygon] `pie_p`, which is easily done
> by replacing `x` by the ray.

```
 n_p DOT (o + td) + d_p = 0 <=> t = (-d_p - n_p DOT o) / (n_p DOT d)
```

> If the denominator `|n_p DOT d| < epsilon`, where `epsilon` is very small
> number, then the ray is considered
> parallel to the polygon plane and no
> intersection occurs. Otherwise, the
> intersection point, `p`, of the ray and
> the polygon plane is computed: `p = o + td`. Thereafter, the problem of
> deciding whether `p` is inside the
> polygon is reduced from three to two
> dimensions...

See the book for more details.

Comment: This was more of a general reference question, but its true that soft surfer has the most up to date algorithm.

Comment: Very long after the original post, I know, but link is 404 now

Comment: @MoteZart https://web.archive.org/web/20210330124410/http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html

Answer (score 3):

```
struct point
{
    float x
    float y
    float z
}

struct ray
{
    point R1
    point R2
}

struct polygon
{
    point P[]
    int count
}

float dotProduct(point A, point B)
{
    return A.x*B.x + A.y*B.y + A.z*B.z
}

point crossProduct(point A, point B)
{
    return point(A.y*B.z-A.z*B.y, A.z*B.x-A.x*B.z, A.x*B.y-A.y*B.x)
}

point vectorSub(point A, point B)
{
    return point(A.x-B.x, A.y-B.y, A.z-B.z) 
}

point scalarMult(float a, Point B)
{
    return point(a*B.x, a*B.y, a*B.z)
}

bool findIntersection(ray Ray, polygon Poly, point& Answer)
{
    point plane_normal = crossProduct(vectorSub(Poly.P[1], Poly.P[0]), vectorSub(Poly.P[2], Poly.P[0]))

    float denominator = dotProduct(vectorSub(Ray.R2, Poly.P[0]), plane_normal)

    if (denominator == 0) { return FALSE } // ray is parallel to the polygon

    float ray_scalar = dotProduct(vectorSub(Poly.P[0], Ray.R1), plane_normal)

    Answer = vectorAdd(Ray.R1, scalarMult(ray_scalar, Ray.R2))

    // verify that the point falls inside the polygon

    point test_line = vectorSub(Answer, Poly.P[0])
    point test_axis = crossProduct(plane_normal, test_line)

    bool point_is_inside = FALSE

    point test_point = vectorSub(Poly.P[1], Answer)
    bool prev_point_ahead = (dotProduct(test_line, test_point) > 0)
    bool prev_point_above = (dotProduct(test_axis, test_point) > 0)

    bool this_point_ahead
    bool this_point_above

    int index = 2;
    while (index < Poly.count)
    {
        test_point = vectorSub(Poly.P[index], Answer)
        this_point_ahead = (dotProduct(test_line, test_point) > 0)

        if (prev_point_ahead OR this_point_ahead)
        {
            this_point_above = (dotProduct(test_axis, test_point) > 0)

            if (prev_point_above XOR this_point_above)
            {
                point_is_inside = !point_is_inside
            }
        }

        prev_point_ahead = this_point_ahead
        prev_point_above = this_point_above
        index++
    }

    return point_is_inside
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whole book chapters have been devoted to this particular requirement - it's too long to describe a suitable algorithm here.  I'd suggest reading any number of reference works in computer graphics, in particular:

- Introduction to Ray Tracing, ed. Andrew S. Glassner, ISBN 0122861604

Comment: Good book, I wrote my own ray tracer following it.

Comment: Me too :)   It doesn't do polygons yet though!

Answer (score 1):

```
function Collision(PlaneOrigin,PlaneDirection,RayOrigin,RayDirection)
    return RayOrigin-RayDirection*Dot(PlaneDirection,RayOrigin-PlaneOrigin)/Dot(PlaneDirection,RayDirection)
end
```

(PlaneDirection is the unit vector which is perpendicular to the plane)